# how to change a file's content for a specific process only?

Tags: files, process, chroot, namespace

For the purpose of this question, let us assume that there is a file (`/path/to/file`) in the filesystem with a certain content like this:

```
$> cat /path/to/file
this is the content of the
file /path/to/file
```

I am happy with almost all processes running (and having reading access to this file), reading this content.
There should however (**and this is the core of the question**) be a specific process, which when reading from `/path/to/file` should be provided with different file content.

```
$> cat /path/to/file
this is the DIFFERNT content of the
file /path/to/file
```

How can I somehow spoof the file content for a specific process?

Some guesses of mine, which road to take would be solitions related to :

- symlinking trick
- (linux) namespaces (filesystem namespace) trick
- `chroot` trick
- `$LD_PRELOAD` hooking trick
- overlayfs

My platform is GNU/linux, but if there is a POSIX way to achieve it that would be even better :)

**Update**

What would be a good solution/answer?

A criterium for a good solution/answer would be that it is possible to achieve "different file content for specific process", without needing interaction of the root user, eventhough the ideally the spoofed file should
not be user-writeable in the first place.

Another good criterium would be that the modification of the file process shown to the process is specific, and ideally without sort of race-condition.

## Background

Mozilla firefox uses 2 zip archives `/usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja` and `/usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja`, which contain a fair deal of firefox' code (mostly  the stuff writen in Javascript), by spoofing the file I would be able to modify my version of firefox (include some features I cannot anymore implement as a extension, provided dropped XPCOM support and disliked addon-siging coercion)

Comment: Have you considered mounting an image with the spoofed file to `/path/to`? Like `mount spoof.img /path/to/`.

Comment: @GuilhermeCosta I have not. Would such a solution anyway change the content of `/path/to` for **all processes** not only my specific one? Should I compare henceforth with an `namespace` `unshare`?

Comment: @GuilhermeCosta That's what Stéphane proposes. But it needs the mount namespace, otherwise all processes would see the same content.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, mount namespaces is one approach:

```
$ cat file
foo
$ cat other-file
bar
$ sudo unshare -m zsh -c 'mount --bind other-file file; USERNAME=$SUDO_USER; cat file'
bar
$ cat file
foo
```

Above using `zsh` to restore the uid/gids of the original user for the hijacked cat command.

Comment: Thank you. Still some question left: I remember that - some time ago - using the `unshare` for stuff related to  **user_namespaces**(7) was not accessible for non-root-priveledged users, yet here we we use `unshare` only for the **mount_namespaces**(7). Can we drop the sudo somehow?

Comment: @humanityANDpeace, you could do `unshare -Urm sh -c 'mount --bind other-file file; cat file'` but then `cat` runs as the `root` user of that new user namespace. You may be able to go back to the original uid, but probably not with the `unshare` utility.

Comment: thanks Stéphane Chazelas, thanks for responding, I see that to unshare as non-root implies using the Usernamespace, something which on debian, ubuntu and arch seems either not enabled in kernel or needing a kernel knob, hence being farther away than a `/etc/sudoers` exception. Guess I have to wait till user_namespace gains further traction, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to do it with [preloading](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/simple-ld-preload-tutorial/) to wedge some code between the program and the system library, by  a small piece of code. This assumes that the program is a dynamically linked binary, or a script executed by a dynamically linked binary (i.e. it isn't statically linked). Write the following code to a file `override_fopen.c`:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#ifndef FROM
#error "Define FROM to the path to override in double quotes, e.g. -DFROM='\"/bad\"'"
#endif
#ifndef TO
#error "Define TO to the path to use instead in double quotes, e.g. -DFROM='\"/good\"'"
#endif
FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode) {
    void *(*original_fopen)(const char *, const char *) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fopen");
    if (!strcmp(path, FROM)) {
        path = TO;
    }
    return original_fopen(path, mode);
}
int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...) {
    int (*original_open)(const char *, int, ...) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open");
    int ret;
    va_list args;
    if (!strcmp(path, FROM)) {
        path = TO;
    }
    va_start(args, oflag);
    if (oflag & O_CREAT) {
        ret = original_open(path, oflag, (mode_t)va_arg(args, mode_t));
    } else {
        ret = original_open(path, oflag);
    }
    va_end(args);
    return ret;
}
```

Compile with the following command (that's for Linux, other Unix variants may require different options). Note the quotes around the path you want to override.

```
gcc -DFROM='"/path/to/file"' -DTO='"/path/to/alternate/content"' -D_GNU_SOURCE -O -Wall -fPIC -shared -o override_fopen.so override_fopen.c -ldl
```

Run the program as follows (on OSX, use `DYLD_PRELOAD` instead of `LD_PRELOAD`):

```
LD_PRELOAD=./override_fopen.so ./myexe
```

This only works if the program is calling the `fopen` or `open` library function. If it calls some other function, you'll need to override that one. You can use [`ltrace`](http://ltrace.org/) to see what library calls the program makes.

Comment: I guess with regards to what I hoped for, i.e. an answer that does work without root priveledge involvement, the preload solution seems preferable, yet it will only work if the open syscall is issued via using dynamic linking feature. I will accept this answer once I made sure the namespace mount option of @Stéphane Chazelas' answer is impossible without root access of sorts. both answers have their long- and shortcomings, thanks