# Make one program use a special resolv.conf

Tags: files, filesystems, process, chroot, resolv.conf

I want to cheat a program to use a special `/etc/resolv.conf` file, that in turn will force it to use a nonstandard nameserver.

The obvious solution is to recreate the whole filesystem except one file and use a chroot. But may be there is a simpler hack for doing this.

[how to change a file's content for a specific process only?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361195/how-to-change-a-files-content-for-a-specific-process-only) gives solutions that work in many cases, but not for `/etc/resolv.conf`: `LD_PRELOAD` doesn't catch when the resolver inside libc opens `/etc/resolv.conf`, and a bind mount doesn't work to override a symbolic link (if the link target is missing or when the link is changed afterwards).

EDIT: A relevant question is [How do I mount a file on top of a broken symbolic link?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429724/) and there is no universal solution found

Comment: Yes. You can run it in a different mount namespace.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor how to overwrite a single file afterwards? If I just run `mount --bind newresolv /tmp/mnt/etc/resolv.conf` it will follow the link path or, in my case where the link path is nonexistent, it fails with an error `mount point is a symbolic link to nowhere`

Comment: One way is with `unshare`, see duplicate. There is probably a way to do it without root privileges (maybe fuse).

Comment: @gilles I don't think that either answer to the purported dupe applies. Overriding `fopen()` with a `LD_PRELOAD` hack will **not** work when `/etc/resolv.conf` is opened by the resolver (ie via `getaddrinfo()`), and the way to _reliably_ use unshare + bind mount with a "dynamic" symlink like `/etc/resolv.conf` needs to be explained more (at least for me, it's not at all obvious how that could be done; assuming that this Q is linux-only, despite no [linux] tag).

Comment: @mosvy You're right, this is a special case where the usual methods don't necessarily work. I've edited and reopened the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`bubblewrap`](https://github.com/containers/bubblewrap) to create a mount namespace.
It is included in most distributions, since flatpak needs it.

```bsh
bwrap \
    --bind / / \
    --bind /home/user/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf \
    binary parameter1 parameter2d
```

Comment: It looks a little bit like bubblewrap and overlayfs are superficially similar.  Can you briefly discuss the similarities and/or differences?  Why would a user choose bubblewrap over overlayfs?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' bubblewrap in OP's case will mount over `/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf` (or `/run/systemd...`) rather than `/etc/resolv.conf` (which is still a symlink).

Answer (score 0):

One can use [`overlayfs`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/overlayfs.html) to avoid duplication. If it's temporary, everything can be done using `/tmp`. Combined with a mount namespace, this can then be made to affect a single application. To be prepared from root (it does work with an user+mount namespace where a normal user is mapped as root, but without privileged assistance and/or recent kernel for pid translation, user mappings wouldn't help to do something useful).

- create a new mount namespace
- create an `overlayfs` in this mount namespace
- bind mount this overlayfs back over `/etc`
- change contents (eg delete the `/etc/resolv.conf` symlink then create the regular file `/etc/resolv.conf` with custom content)
- run application, still from this mount namespace

Example:

```
mkdir /tmp/upper /tmp/work /tmp/fake_etc
unshare -m
```

next commands are run in the new mount namespace:

```
mount -t overlay -olowerdir=/etc,upperdir=/tmp/upper,workdir=/tmp/work overlay_etc /tmp/fake_etc
```

then just cover `/etc` with the one used to fake its contents:

```
mount --bind /tmp/fake_etc /etc
```

and do changes (affecting only the overlayfs in the mount namespace):

```
rm /etc/resolv.conf
echo nameserver 192.0.2.2 > /etc/resolv.conf
```

AFAIK can't mount a *mount* namespace to keep a reference. If needed one can use instead a PID reference from the mount namespace:

```
# echo $$
325304
```

Either in the same shell or in a separate (root) shell by running this:

```
nsenter -t 325304 --mount
```

then following the previous example (with a nameserver 192.0.2.2 that isn't reachable):

```
# su - -c 'ping stackexchange.com' someuser 
ping: stackexchange.com: Name or service not known
```

While anywhere else `ping` will work as usual.